# Populate data in C# entity from different tables

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, enterprise-library

I've three tables:

**Car**

[image]

**Parts**

[image]

**SubParts**

[image]

Now I want to get data from all the three tables, which is easy by performing inner join I can easily get that. My SQL query is

```
Select C.Id AS CarId,C.Name AS CarName
, P.Id AS PartsId,P.Name AS PartsName
, SP.Id AS SubPartsId,SP.Name AS SubPartsName 
from Car C
INNER JOIN Parts P on C.Id=P.CarId
INNER JOIN SubParts SP on P.Id=SP.PartsId
```

In C# I've same entities with same properties as that of table columns and the same name as that of the table, now I want to populate data from a single query in three different entities without iterating each record returned from SQL query. Is there any that can be done in using ADO.NET or Enterprise Library(more preferable).

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use entity framework?

Comment: It would help a lot if you could include the classes, in particular what kind of types you are using for the collection...

Comment: @Jakotheshadows : Yeah as I'm working on an old project an its on Enterprise library

Answer (score 0):

Use the `join` from LINQ.

```
var innerJoinQuery =
    from car in cars
    join part in parts on car.Id equals part.CarId
    join subPart in subParts on part.Id equals subPart.PartId
    select new {
        CarId = car.Id, 
        CarName = car.Name,
        PartsId = part.Id,
        PartsName = part.Name,
        SubPartsId = subPart.Id,
        SubPartsName = subPart.Name
    };
```

Comment: I want to populate data from stored procedure to my respective entities.